# How to choose and design a waveform generator such that it generates signals of mentioned rms voltage, Vi and of frequency f given below?

Tags: design, signal

Type: Sinusoidal
Vi = 35 mV
f = 30 kHz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways:

- Use a micro with an internal or external DAC. Something like the [dsPIC33FJ64GP802](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en532310) has a nice dual 16-bit DAC that goes up to 100kHz.
- Design an analogue oscillator, such as a [Wien bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien_bridge_oscillator) or [Phase shift oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-shift_oscillator), both suited for this type of application (or indeed a Hartley/Colpitts)
- By a dedicated DDS ([Direct Digital Synthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_digital_synthesizer)) IC or similar and use this.

Comment: @dds http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD9850.pdf

Comment: There are some super-cheap prebuilt DDS boards sold on eBay.com, that may help the OP - They work, I have a couple. e.g. [AD9850 board](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1pcs-AD9850-DDS-Signal-Generator-Module-/370778337988?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item56541c72c4) for $2.99 shipped, compared to $23 for the [bare chip from Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/AD9850BRSZ/AD9850BRSZ-ND/621913).

Answer (score 2):

It basically depends on what you are doing and your specifications.
If the signal is needed for basic lab tests and you have a waveform generator at hand, e.g. [Agilent 33220A/33250A](http://www.home.agilent.com/en/pd-127539-pn-33220A/function-arbitrary-waveform-generator-20-mhz?&cc=IT&lc=ita), definitely go for it: dedicated generators have very low noise floor, very high spurious-free dynamic range, very high quality output stages - they are test instrumentation engineered for the purpose. Most commercial waveform generators are based on DDS as mentioned above.

I would also recommend [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/sloa087/sloa087.pdf) for a basic practical understanding of some common analog oscillators in case you have to design one.